# What to do if an edit invalidates my answer?

Tags: discussion, rollbacks, rollback-wars

I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33926904/3100115) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926771/duplicate-values-in-a-dictionary-python)  then this answer was [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33926842/2)ed with same solution. I then asked the post's owner to rollback his edit because I feel it invalidates my answer and he comment(comment that he deleted later) that he doesn't know how to do it so I edited the post but that triggered a rollback war. I then raise a custom flag that got declined.

Now my question is what should I do in situation like this?

Comment: Delete your answer and look for another question (asked by a better user) to answer?

Comment: Am I missing something? How does it invalidate your answer?

Comment: @Rob please see the edit history.

Comment: I can't see what you are complaining about. the Edit History shows that the author of the answer adds a couple of line and you remove them so infact your more likely to be the one invalidating their answer. also how does one answer invalidate your own answer? you says *"please see the edit history. Perhaps you will understand why I edited the first place"* in one comment but all i see if you removing 2 lines the author added for no reason

Comment: @Memor-X I removed those lines because it's the solution I posted. Can you take a closer look at revision 2 inline?

Comment: @user3100115 Having someone else post the same content doesn't invalidate your answer though. As long as neither person is plagiarizing, there's no problem with both people having the same solution.

Comment: @resueman what if that content is an edit to their post after you posted your answer? if there is a post with the same content I will not update my answer  with that content.

Comment: If a custom flag was declined then that's your answer, just move on...

Comment: @user3100115 so? the author posts their original answer than makes an edit 76 seconds later showing that most of their original code can be typed out in one line and passed strait into `sort`. are you claiming that in 76 seconds they read your answer, copied your code and altered it to look near identical to their own? are you claiming they stole your idea of doing it all in one line because if so you can be accused for the same thing aswell as another answer was posted 68 seconds before yours showed how you can do it in one line

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not uncommon for someone to arrive at a similar solution to yours shortly after you've posted the answer.  Admittedly, 10 minutes later isn't exactly "shortly after", but it's still within reason - perhaps they're a slow typist, or were watching videos on YouTube while formulating the answer.

Flags on this would be rightfully declined since there's no *hard* evidence to suggest that your answer was "invalidated" or plagiarized.  Now, if the answer were a bit older (let's say for the sake of argument, a day or so), *then* you might have a case, since it's not a matter of two people arriving at the same solution **around the same time**.

You should keep your answer there and don't fret the other one.  **Definitely do not rollback their answer** in this scenario, as they have done nothing that would explicitly merit a rollback of content.

Comment: I think the edit was made one minute after the OP's answer (21:42:24 vs 21:43:40), not ten minutes.

Comment: @resueman:  Then there's even less reason to fret.

Comment: @resueman technically, it was 76 seconds between the accepted answer being posted and the edit with the added code